# CSS clip-path property: relative path ➰

Tags: css, svg, specifications, clip-path

I'm trying to use the css `clip-path` property with a `path`. But I'm failing to construct a path that's defined in a relative way, similar to for example `clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);`.

I have tried using

```css
clip-path: path('M 0 0 h100% v100% v-100%v-100%');
```

but both Chrome and FF say that's invalid.

[The MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#syntax) show an example which looks a bit like it's using a relative coordinate system:

```css
clip-path: clip-path: path('M0.5,1 C0.5,1,0,0.7,0,0.3 A0.25,0.25,1,1,1,0.5,0.3 A0.25,0.25,1,1,1,1,0.3 C1,0.7,0.5,1,0.5,1 Z');
```

But if I'm not mistaken, that's also just absolute values, resulting in a very small clip path.

This [article by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/an-initial-implementation-of-clip-path-path/#and-heres-a-demo) also just uses absolute coordinates.

I even checked the [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#the-clip-path), but the mentioned `<basic-shape>` doesn't even include `path`, if I read this correctly (reading specs is not something I frequently do …).

I am aware I could solve this by using the `url(…)` syntax, pointing to an svg clipPath. That's what apparently everybody does right now. My questions remain:

- it it possible to use a relative syntax for `clip-path: path`?
- if no, is this planned? Or am I the only one finding this useful?!
- am I reading the spec right? Is `path` not specified (yet) and 'just' being implemented by browsers?
- (bonus question): what are good sources to look for this kind of information?

Comment: The current spec (WIP) is [CSS Shapes Level 2](//drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes-2/) by the CSSWG of W3C. Relative paths will be possible with the [`shape`](//drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes-2/#shape-function) function. And yes, you’re not the only one eagerly awaiting this feature… (for me, it’s the ability to define separate subpaths, using intuitive CSS syntax, and interpolation of CSS values, as opposed to fixed pixel values as is the case with `path`).